# Not able to select date using java script executor in Selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I want to select a particular date using JavaScript executor but am not able to select and I also didn't get any execution.

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("http://spicejet.com/");
String date ="11/03";
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='ctl00_mainContent_view_date1']"));
element.click();

DatePicker(driver,element,date);

public static void DatePicker(WebDriver driver, WebElement element, String date)
{   
    JavascriptExecutor js = ((JavascriptExecutor) driver);
    js.executeScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('value'," + date + ");" , element);
}
```

In inspect element I get this

```
<td class="ui-datepicker-week-end ui-datepicker-current-day" 
    data-year="2018" 
    data-month="3" 
    data-event="click" 
    data-handler="selectDay">
    <a class="ui-state-default ui-state-active" href="#">15</a>
</td>
```

Comment: try `//input[@name='ctl00$mainContent$txt_Fromdate']/following-sibling::button[@class='ui-datepicker-trigger']` this

Comment: Setting the value with JS won't work. You need to click Depart Date and then click the calendar to set the date.

Answer (score 0):

Try to get all the elements that are inside the "td" tag and place it inside a List . Then make a FOR looking for the day you want to select and click on it. Here is the code I use to solve this type of problem.

```
WebElement dateWidget = driver.findElement("ui-datepicker-div");    
List<WebElement> columns = dateWidget.findElements(By.tagName("td"));
    for (WebElement cell : columns) {
        if (cell.getText().equals(day)) {
            cell.findElement(By.linkText(day)).click();
        }
    }
```